# window.open(URL,name,specs,replace) ?? name Vs replace

Tags: javascript, dom

If current window is`www.myparent.com` by clicking a button-a, it invokes this function `window.open('children','same','',??)`. The new page opens as `www.myparent.com/children`

Clicking button-b, it invokes this function `window.open('sub','same','',??)`.

`www.myparent.com/children` is replaced by `www.myparent.com/sub`

Now I want to know, what is the use of `replace (true/false)`. Please take a look the [syntax definition](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp)

Comment: In case you didn't know, W3Schools is not affiliated with the W3C and thus do not 'define' the syntax. For functions like `window.open` which were not originally in any specifications, it would be better to read the browser vendor's documentation, such as [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/aa740469) for IE and [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/) for Firefox

Comment: Xie Xie Jiang ! i went through firefox (MDN) window.open documentation and found that there is nothing like `replace`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually this is the syntax

```
 window.open(URL,name,specs,replace)
```

and this is the [documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp):

As you can see from the docs, replace

> Optional.Specifies whether the URL creates a new entry or replaces the
>   current entry in the history list. The following values are supported:
>    - true - URL replaces the current document in the history list
>    - false - URL creates a new entry in the history list

If you set it to true, in your history list the page that is opened in the new window replace the page you are currently browsing (I.E you will not have the page in history)

Comment: ok but take a look http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp and i didn't understand the `replace` keyword

Comment: i read already but not understanding `replace (true/false)`, what is this history list

Comment: It affects the Browsing History, the way pages are saved in the browser. In one case your old page is not saved, it's replaced, in the other case your full history is preserved. Don't rely on this function, it's pointless.

Comment: ok, i got it now. many thanks ! what is by default `true or false`

Comment: In javascript if you don't pass an arguments that variable is undefined, which resolve to `false`

Comment: as suggested by jiang, i went through firefox(i am using this browser) [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.open) documentation. i didn't find anything like `replace` keyword so i think it's not a valid keyword for firefox, right? i think you mentioned the same fn in your earlier post. anyway thanks for your time.

Comment: Yes you are right, that was the first link i posted. As i said i don't think you should use the function. If this answer your question, remember to accept the answer

Comment: Does this actually work? The official [source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open#Syntax) makes no mention of that.